# How to display current date/time in Angular disabled form field

Tags: angular

In my Angular Application I am displaying the current date by doing this:

**Ts.file**

```
dateModel: Date = new Date();
```

**html.file**

```
{{currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

How would I display the time also in terms of: HH:mm:ss?

Comment: See this: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe. The docs should be the first place you look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was easy as:

```
{{currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}
```